# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters Junit5 with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm receiving the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.<init>(JUnit5TestLoader.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 13 more
```

Running JUnit 5 in an Eclipse project (no Maven). Does anyone know what causes this issue?
Eclipse version: 2020-12
JUnit Version: 5

I was expecting JUnit 5 to run on Eclipse without further action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re missing one of JUnit’s dependencies, which means that the class isn’t loading. Check you have all of the necessary dependencies in place especially if you’re not using a build tool like Maven.

Comment: OK, can anyone tell me the dependencies I need. Do I nedd all JUnit classes ?

Answer (score 13):

The same error occured to me.

Solution: I had to add the JUnit library to the buildpath. Right click the class -> build path -> configure buildpath -> add libraries -> add JUnit

*At this point one should add the new library not to the module path but to the entire class path.*

JUnit tests are now running for me, though i had the same error as @AlBlue.

Comment: I had to move the JUnit5 library out of the modulepath and into the classpath for it to work.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue because I configured the buildpath with JUnit 5 to the modulepath. Instead you need to configure it in the Classpath.

**EDIT**
As mentioned in the comment:
There are two locations that a library can be added to build path and module path. If you add Junit on module path, the classes are not visible, as they are not packaged in a module

Comment: Please make sure to give a more detailed answer to make clear the steps that manuel need to do to solve his problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just to help out. There are two locations that a library can be added to build path and module path. If you add Junit on module path, the classes are not visible, as they are not packaged in a module.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! 
As mentioned in the last commet, there are two locations that a library can be added.

Answer (score 1):

Add Junite library to Classpath instead of Modulepath, in Java build path window, it solved the problem for me

Answer (score -1):

My problem is resolved as I was trying to run junit test class on STS 4 MacOS. I did:

1. Either add all required jar file of JUnit 5 Jupiter file -

   - junit-jupiter-api-5.8.0.jar
   - annotations-13.0.jar
   - apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar
   - core-0.6.8.jar
   - hoplite-core-2.1.3.jar
   - hoplite-yaml-2.1.3.jar
   - junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.0.jar
   - junit-platform-commons-1.8.0.jar
   - junit-platform-engine-1.8.0.jar
   - junit-platform-launcher-1.8.0.jar
   - junit5-0.6.8.jar
   - kotlin-reflect-1.6.20.jar
   - kotlin-stdlib-1.6.20.jar
   - kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.20.jar
   - kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.10.jar
   - kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar
   - opentest4j-1.2.0.jar
   - slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar
2. OR  add dependency in pom.xml file

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.lemfi.kest</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
   <version>0.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```